# Restart Tor Browser after closing

Tags: tor

Tor Browser freeze crash at random times especially when there is one tab and the page is loading. But the Tor and the Vidalia are still running good.

When Tor Browser(FireFox) freeze crash, how can I restart the browser without clicking 'stop tor' button in the Vidalia Control Panel?

Comment: I voted to reopen. Because like @EliahKagan described, the question is not about the bug.

Answer (score 7):

There should in theory be a way to restart the browser without causing any security concerns, however the developers probably don't view the feature as a priority. On the [official site](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TB) it is seen not as a bug, but as a feature request:

> People want to:
>
> Start Tor Browser Bundle, close Tor Browser for various reasons, leave Tor and/or Vidalia running for various reasons, and restart Tor Browser later.

Again, the [official line](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#TBBCloseBrowser) is that the developers are 'working on a way to make this possible on all platforms'.

None of the current Linux [stable](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/linux/tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.2.39-5-dev-en-US.tar.gz) or [alpha versions](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/linux/tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.3.24-alpha-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz) of `tor browser bundle` currently implement the restart feature. This is because they do not contain the version of `Vidalia` that had the feature which allowed you to restart the browser after closing it. That version of `Vidalia` is discussed in [this request](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6090), although there have been requests and discussion of the feature for all platforms [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6023) and [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5693).

In summary, the aforementioned official sources make it clear that this seemingly simple browser restart feature is not so simple to implement. It would require a specific patched version of `Vidalia`, a specially patched version of `Firefox` (beyond the one already included in the bundle), and much work to make sure that there were no security holes introduced into the software.

There doesn't seem to be a quick way to implement a shell-script to do it unfortunately, so it's just a case of waiting for the developers to implement the feature or trying to help out with the development oneself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is too late to help, but saw this post browsing around for another answer.

The way I relaunch Tor Browser is by pointing a new firefox shortcut to `~/[tor browser directory]/App/Firefox/firefox` and just loading the dang thing from there. If you've used another firefox since, you may have to reconfigure your proxies on the browser

(prefs -> advanced -> network -> settings), but that's `127.0.0.1` and `0` on everything but SOCKS, then for SOCKS5 `127.0.0.1 9150`.

Pretty straightforward.